# why is the console giving me an exception, when startsWith is defined?

Tags: javascript, exception, methods, startswith

ok i am trying to run the following code and i am getting back an exception that startsWith method is undefined. shouldnt this automatically be defined within javascript?

```
var mailArchive = retrieveMails();
var livingCats = {"Spot": true};

for (var mail = 0; mail < mailArchive.length; mail++) {
  var paragraphs = mailArchive[mail].split("\n");
  for (var paragraph = 0;
   paragraph < paragraphs.length;
   paragraph++) {
if (startsWith(paragraphs[paragraph], "born")) {
  var names = catNames(paragraphs[paragraph]);
  for (var name = 0; name < names.length; name++)
    livingCats[names[name]] = true;
}
else if (startsWith(paragraphs[paragraph], "died")) {
  var names = catNames(paragraphs[paragraph]);
  for (var name = 0; name < names.length; name++)
    delete livingCats[names[name]];
  }
 }
}

show(livingCats);
```

Comment: Where is it defined? "shouldnt this automatically be defined within javascript" --- nope

Comment: unless you are using a library that contains that function, there isn't one in javascript

Comment: Looks like a Mozilla-only extension? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @zerkms - Firefox has an experimental string method `.startsWith()`.

Comment: pretty silly that the author of the book would use a method that isnt defined by default, code in question is from http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html

Comment: @user3376521 http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html#p44eb0c2117451fa5

Comment: damn thats what happens when your tired, sorry about that everyone

Answer (score 2):

Some versions of javascript (an experimental method in Firefox) have a `.startsWith()` string method that you would use like:

```
if (paragraphs[paragraph].startsWith("died"))
```

Regular javascript does not have a global function `startsWith()` like you are trying to use so unless you're loading some library that has that function in it, that's why the browser is telling you it's undefined.

---

A recommended solution that would work in any version of JS, would be:

```
if (paragraphs[paragraph].indexOf("died") === 0)
```

instead.

---

Or, you could define the global function you're using:

```
function startsWith(src, find) {
    return src.substr(0, find.length) == find;
}
```

Comment: Or even `paragraphs[paragraph].substring(0, 4) === 'died'` which won't iterate over the whole string.

Comment: how does `if (paragraphs[paragraph].indexOf("died") === 0)` work. indexOf returns an integer, how is it being equal to zero true? why is it zero? how does it know the length of died is 0?

Comment: @user3376521: zero is the index of the first character in the string.

Comment: @user3376521 - `.indexOf()` returns the index where the match starts.  So, the string only starts with that other string if the match starts at `0`.  If `.indexOf()` returns any other value besides `0`, then it didn't start with the desired string.  I'd suggest you read about how `str1.indexOf(str2)` works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Answer (score -2):

It's a method of String, not a global function.

It should be:

```
paragraphs[paragraph].startsWith("born")
```

Comment: It's not supported but majority of browsers, since it doesn't belong to ECMAScript. So `s/It should be/It could be if it was defined in the standard/`

Comment: No matter where it's supported, the usage still is wrong(he didn't specify that he uses a browser where it's not supported)

Comment: your code is wrong as well: your code won't work because `String`'s prototype does not have `startsWith` method defined. "he didn't specify that he uses a browser" --- they specified programming language name. In javascript what you've shown is not defined.

Comment: I'm able to read comments, are you too? Let's assume he uses a browser where it's supported(FF) my code is correct, because in FF String.prototype has these method.

Comment: the question is about javascript, and its syntax + all host objects are defined in ECMAScript. The question is not about crazy extensions someone supports. For the given question - your answer is incorrect, sorry. "Let's assume" --- let's not assume. It's not fortune telling competition, let's base our answers on facts.

Comment: When his question is about JS(especially syntax), it's about the usage of object-methods, and the correct usage of object-methods isn't `method(object,arg)` , it's `object.method(arg)` ....that's a fact, not an assumption.

Comment: "it's about the usage of object-methods" --- that's right. And teaching them how to use arbitrary **valid** method could be an answer (if one additionally demonstrates how to do what OP asked about). Whereas giving an answer with "It should be" and invalid javascript is nonsense from my perspective.

Comment: Experimental features are **invalid** from your perspective? I wonder how webpages would look like today when nobody had been started with experiments.

Comment: that's right. Experimental thing that is not a part of a standard and is only supported by one browser vendor is invalid from syntactically valid language perspective. An important note: you **did not** even mention anywhere in your answer that it is either experimental or supported only by FF. You just stated "It should be" which is just incorrect.

Comment: What a perfect definition, it's like **crossing a road against red lights is prohibited(except there are enough people that do it)** . BTW: the state of the extension has been mentioned 3 times in the comments before my answer, it should have been clear what it's about)

Comment: "crossing a road against red lights is prohibited(except there are enough people that do it)" --- not even close. It would be: "crossing a road against red lights is prohibited. If it's allowed by the road code - then it's not prohibited".

Comment: Mmmmh,... ***is not a part of a standard and is only supported by one browser vendor*** ...this suggests that it would  be valid when this (currently)non-standard-feature would be supported by the majority of browsers

Comment: "this suggests" --- no it doesn't. That's how you want to see it.

Comment: when it doesn't, how can the number of supported browsers be relevant  at all?

Comment: the second part was just to emphasize the incorrect state of the whole solution. Read it as: it not only should not work according the specification, but also it's not implemented anywhere but in 1 browser.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53944/discussion-between-zerkms-and-dr-molle)